# "keyup" event and "keydown" being called by the same event handler

Tags: javascript

Hope your having a wonderful week :D

I have just started up with JavaScript and was wondering is it possible to handle the two events from one event-handler.

So for example

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",handleKeys);
document.addEventListener("keyup",handleKeys);
    function handleKeys(e , a){
        switch(e.keyCode) {
           case '0': return isSomething = a; // a = false | true for keydown and keyup
       }
    }
```

Would something like this be possible

Comment: Yes this does work

Comment: Yes, that works. Functions are first class citizens in JS, so you can pass them around just fine.

Comment: Did you run this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, though you'll need to set the 2nd param of handleKeys, or it will be `undefined`.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => handleKeys(e, true));
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => handleKeys(e, false));

function handleKeys(e, down) {
  console.log(down);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, however - dont do it in this way - is better to use two separate handlers. If they have shared code, then move that code to separate third method which will be call with that handlers.